# How to See and Edit my Hotmail Rules?

Tags: outlook.com, email-rules

(this is a question I had myself. I eventually found the answer, and hope that by posting it here, someone else will be saved the pain I had)

I have created a number of rules for moving mail into various folders. I wanted to see if I could consolidate some of the rules, as there were a number of senders all of whose mail should be moved to one particular folder.

The problem was that I couldn't find the Rules page!

I thought it had something to do with Options, so I clicked Options->More options.

There's an entire page of options, but I couldn't see anything that had to do with moving mail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to get to the rules page:

- On the left pane, where it says, `Inbox`, `Folders`, `Quick Views`, and `Messenger`, if you hover your cursor over `Folders`, a cog will appear in the highlighted area. Click the cog and go to `Manage Rules`.
- You can click on `Options` > `Shortcuts` > `Create Inbox Rules`

Answer (score 4):

Since Hotmail has moved to Outlook.com, the new way to check your rules is as follows:

**Right Click** the "**Folders**" drop-down tile on the left-hand side plane. **Select** "**Manage Rules**". You should be able to edit and create new rules from here.

Answer (score 2):

For the latest version of Outlook Online at the time of this writing, it is to go to `settings icon top right --> options --> mail --> automatic processing --> inbox and sweep rules`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally located the correct page, under "*Rules for sorting new messages*". It's on ManageRules.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this situation when I accidentally set a rule for my supervisor's work email address. Every time she'd email me, it'd go directly to the deleted folder.

To solve this, I went to upper right and clicked on the "lightning bolt" looking icon, clicked more mail options, under CUSTOMIZING OUTLOOK there's an option for "rules for sorting new messages", and I clicked on that. I then clicked on where I had seen her name/email and deleted it. That deleted the rule and I was able to get all of her emails now.

Answer (score 0):

MSN Hotmail/Outlook answer: when an email is selected and you have the sweep option in the top blue ribbon pull down menu, select "sweep" and at the bottom of the pull down box is a "manage rules" option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hotmail via outlook.live.com, then just click on the button at top stating "Sweep", You will get to creating a new rule for selected message. As same tab at below you will see "View rules". Click on it and you will see all previously created rules.